# Google app engine: empty property in datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Let say I have a model:

```
class A(db.Model):
    B = db.StringProperty()
    C = db.StringProperty()
```

How do I query if I wanted to search all empty property (not None, just empty) in C using python?

Answer (score 4):

From [GAE Python documents](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Restrictions_on_Queries)

> It is not possible to perform a query
>   for entities that are missing a given
>   property. One alternative is to create
>   a fixed (modeled) property with a
>   default value of None, then create a
>   filter for entities with None as the
>   property value.

Answer (score -2):

Well if you want to return all rows with empty C properties you could do this.

empty = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM A WHERE C = ""')